# How to get a list of available channels from Pusher?

Tags: pusher

I read the docs and I understand that channels are created on client demand. However, it seems to me, it should still be possible for a client to get a list of channels that you can subscribe to and and get some meaningful data. How do I do this?

I ask because, for instance, there are no docs for Bitstamp API, which uses Pusher, and it's rather difficult to understand what is possible to do with it. Knowing what channels I can use would at least clear things up a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get a list of channels, but only via the Pusher Web API:
http://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide/interact_rest_api#application-channels

You can't do this via the JavaScript client.

So, it sounds like Bitstamp should provide a way of exposing what channels are available as part of their own API.